# How can I loop through n-dimensional sparse matrix (created by own class)?

Tags: c#, loops, multidimensional-array, iteration

I have two classes

```
class CSparseMatrix:
{
            public int NumberOfDimensions { get; set;}
            public int DefaultNumber { get; set; }
            List<int> dimensionsRanges = new List<int>(); // that's specify dimension of ranges, f.e. {100, 100, 100, 120..}

            List<CSparseCell> cells = new List<CSparseCell>(); // contains only values different from default for this matrix
}
class CSparseCell {
            public int Value { get; set; }
            public List<int> coordinates = new List<int>();
}
```

And the problem is: how to loop through this `CSparseMatrix` and output all ranges with values in format like: `[0, 0, 0, 0] - *value*, [0, 0, 0, 1] - *value*, [0, 0, 0, 2] - *value*, ...[dimensionsRanges[0]-1, dimensionsRanges[1]-1, dimensionsRanges[2]-1, dimensionsRanges[3]-1] - *value*` so through all ranges and output all values (we can have any number of this dimensions).
That means that in program we had to to output all values of matrix, which can have any number of dimensions and ranges could be different. But we don't know what this number of dimensions will be so can't use n-nested loops, and actually I have no idea of algorithm or method how to iterate through all values from `List<int> dimensionsRanges`

The way, we get the specific value from this "matrix" is

```
            public int GetValueFromCell(List<int> coordinate)
            {
                foreach(CSparseCell cell in cells)
                {
                    if(cell.coordinates.All(coordinate.Contains)) {
                        return cell.Value;
                    }
                }
                return DefaultNumber;
            }
```

Comment: I am finding this question a little unclear. So do you want all cells and all coordinates, where.... all indexes are 0 except one you choose ?

Comment: @TheGeneral i'm sorry that wrote unclear question. Tried to edit it to be more clear. You can ask more and sorry in advance! Thanks

Comment: I'm curious what kind of sparse matrix is this?  Could you show the method that allows you to get a value at a given point in the matrix?

Comment: @MikeJ added this informaion

Comment: Your `GetValueFromCell` seems a bit problematic to me - does the order of the coordinates not matter?

Comment: Having to search the entire matrix for any given point would make this extremely inefficient unless this is very sparse - almost no cells in it.  Is there a reason you can't use a traditional sparse matrix implementation?

Comment: Note also that the your current GetValueFromCell does not treat the coordinates as a unique ID.  For that you would need Enumerable.SequenceEquals (cell.coordinate, this.coordinate).  But maybe that is intentional?

Comment: @ yes, I need to use this just. And really thank you for information about  Enumerable.SequenceEquals, it's really cool here!)

Comment: @mkip Now I am wondering if this is homework, because that is a pretty poor implementation for `CSparseMatrix` :)

Comment: how do you set the bounds for each dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say your matrix is large, avoid returning `CSparseCell` by pushing the `Value` lookup to the answer computation.

You create a method to return all the coordinates in the sparse matrix, using a helper method to increment coordinates. NOTE: I changed the coordinate increment method to use a `for` loop instead of `do` which might be easier to understand (?).

```
void IncCoord(ref List<int> aCoord) { // ref not needed, just for documentation
    for (var curDim = NumberOfDimensions - 1; curDim >= 0; --curDim) {
        if (aCoord[curDim] == dimensionsRanges[curDim] - 1) // handle carry
            aCoord[curDim] = 0;
        else {
             ++aCoord[curDim];
            break;
        }
   }
}

public IEnumerable<List<int>> AllCoords() {
    var curCellCoord = Enumerable.Repeat(0, NumberOfDimensions).ToList();
    var numCells = dimensionsRanges.Product();
    for (int j1 = 0; j1 < numCells; ++j1) {
        yield return curCellCoord.ToList();
        IncCoord(ref curCellCoord);
    }
}
```

Now you can use this method to get all `Value`s and you can format the output however you like. Assuming `t` is a `CSparseMatrix`:

```
var ans = t.AllCoords().Select(c => $"[{c.Join(",")}] - {t.GetValueFromCell(c)}");
```

A couple of helper extension methods are used:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    public static int Product(this IEnumerable<int> src) => src.Aggregate(1, (a,n) => a * n);
}

public static class StringExt {
    public static string Join<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, string sep) => String.Join(sep, items);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for ur response, will check it soon, but now I have additional few questions pls: 1)this matrix could be really big: can we avoid returning CSparseCell?If it's possible, could you write it pls 2) You wrote "PPS", but i didn't realise what do we need to change then, so if you can, I will be glad, if you add that lines of code to your response pls. - And sure again: thanks for your response anyway!

Comment: You could make the default a static instance.  That would be much safer if his cells where immutable of course...  troublesome also that you have to search the entire matrix to find a single cell.

Comment: @MikeJ I agree, but I wasn't re-writing the `CSparseMatrix` class (yet). I also find the way the coordinates are looked up questionable...

Comment: @mkip I re-wrote the code to avoid creating many unused `CSparseCell`s. I agree with @MikeJ that a better implementation of `CSparseMatrix` is possible, preferably using a custom `Coordinate` class based on `int[]` (with an `operator++`) and having `operator[ params int[] coord]` to get values, as well as using a `Dictionary<Coordinate,int>` for storage, unless lookup speed isn't that important.

Comment: Now I see I missed his desire to iterate over the entire address space getting all cells.  Does sound a lot like homework eh?

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is how number of dimensions helps.  Without actually setting a bounds for a each dimensions how can you possibly iterate over the address space?  Or am I misunderstanding what AllCords is supposed to do?

Comment: @MikeJ `NumberOfDimensions` is useful, but `dimensionsRanges` is the key. It contains the maximum value for each dimension, which means you can treat the coordinate as a n-digit number with each digit being in a different base.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a couple suggestions.  First tying the coordinate and the value together complicate things.  It'd be much better to separate those two.

Secondly, having to search the entire array to find a single cell makes it very inefficient.  You can create a simple sparse matrix out of a dictionary.  This not at all the best way but with the unknown key requirements you have given it's at least better than the array.  (is it really a matrix if the key is 1..n ?)

Here's an example. First we make the coordinates their own type.

```
readonly struct SparseCoord : IEquatable<SparseCoord>
{
    public static SparseCoord ToCoordinate(params int[] coords)
    {
        return new SparseCoord(coords);
    }

    public SparseCoord(int[] c)
    {
        this.Coordinate = new int[c?.Length ?? 0];

        if (null != c)
            c.CopyTo(this.Coordinate, 0);
    }

    public int[] Coordinate { get; }

    public bool Equals([AllowNull] SparseCoord other)
    {
        return Enumerable.SequenceEqual(this.Coordinate, other.Coordinate);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is SparseCoord c)
            return this.Equals(c);

        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var hash = new HashCode();
        foreach (var i in this.Coordinate)
            hash.Add(i);

        return hash.ToHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append('(');
        foreach (var i in this.Coordinate)
        {
            sb.Append(i);
            sb.Append(',');
        }
        sb.Length = sb.Length - 1;
        sb.Append(')');
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then we create a sparse matrix using a dictionary as the storage.  Note this is incomplete obviously as there's no way to clear it partially or completely but again it's just an example.

```
class SparseMatrix : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<SparseCoord, int>>
{
    Dictionary<SparseCoord, int> cells = new Dictionary<SparseCoord, int>();

    public int this[SparseCoord coord]
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.cells.TryGetValue(coord, out var ret))
                return ret;
            return 0;
        }
        set
        {
            this.cells[coord] = value;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<SparseCoord, int>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.cells.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Then you can add values and iterate over the contents:

```
    static void Main(string[] _)
    {
        SparseMatrix matrix = new SparseMatrix();

        matrix[SparseCoord.ToCoordinate(1, 2, 3)] = 1;
        matrix[SparseCoord.ToCoordinate(5, 6, 7)] = 2;

        foreach (var value in matrix)
            Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
```

Finally I would reiterate that if your matrix really is going to get "big" as you said in a comment then you should invest some time in looking at some well known implementations of sparse matrix.